Visual Studio 22 WPF - New controls added in designer are not recognized by IntelliSense in code behind
I am currently writing a WPF application in visual studio. Every time I add a control to my form in the designer, it is not recognized by IntelliSense until I completely restart Visual Studio. I receive the error "control does not exist in the current context". This is regardless of the control type or the form. The same thing happens with UserControls. If it makes any difference, the solution was originally a winforms solution that now also has wpf projects in it.
I have tried building, rebuilding, and cleaning both the project and solution, which does not address the issue. The only solution that fixes it is to restart visual studio completely. Current versioning: C# |.NET Framework 4.8 | Visual Studio Professional 2022 17.9.5

I have the same issue with Visual Studio latest preview version , WPF .NET CORE v8

Microsoft rather than fixing issues on .net8 or 4.8, they are focusing on .net9

just report https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report

Just sent in the report to microsoft thanks for sending that link

Could you please share the link to the issue reported in the Developer Community? Is it possible share your project structure and the steps to reproduce the issue for me to analyze?
